# 50-90'C color changing chemical to use as warning marker for hot electronics?

Tags: thermodynamics, home-experiment, temperature, color, phase

I am testing electronics with many potentially unstable contacts, and I wish to monitor if they rise above 50 to 90 degrees Celsius, i.e. using carbon paper that would darken progressively from 50 to 90.

The substance should stay a specific warning color if it goes too high and not change hues again same as thermochromic pigment, so that I can detect high temps.

I hope you know a chemistry trick that could help? Thank you.

Comment: wax melts at 60-100 degrees so perhaps i can find a solution using it. Color change would be more safe and visible.

Comment: Some "invisible inks" could help you, and most of them are easily available, but I do not know what the optimal temperature for their change is. You might want to experiment with that a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [commercial](http://www.hallcrest.com/our-products/special-effect-ink-coating/thermochromic-permanent-change-ink)  [sources](http://www.hallcrest.com/) for thermochromic permanent-change ink, but you might also try [thermal printer paper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_paper). You might need to check if there is a time-dependence on the color change, as well as temperature dependence. The printer paper is available at Amazon, Staples and elsewhere for less than US$20 / package, but you might just test a cash-register receipt, many of which are on thermal paper. According to this [PDF](https://www.brother-usa.com/Mobile/pdfs/white_papers/ThermalPaperWhitePaper.pdf), most start to darken at 79 C.